# Not Able to login using .Net Web Application (C#) in NetSuite

Tags: c#, web, service, authentication, wsdl

Not Able to login using .Net Web Application(C#) in Net Suite...
If Any One Have Solution please give me step by step

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService();

            service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            //invoke the login operation
            Passport passport = new Passport();
            passport.account = "TSTDRV986543";
            passport.email = txtUserName.Text;
            passport.password = txtPassword.Text;
            RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
            role.internalId = "3";
            passport.role = role;
            Status status = service.login(passport).status;
}
}
```

I am using https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2014_2_0/netsuite.wsdl This url to import web services and also I already change all URL type.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the SuiteTalk sample applications for sample requests to NetSuite, both in C# and in Java: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml

It is also possible to troubleshoot the SOAP requests and responses by going in NetSuite, under Setup -> Integration -> Web Service Usage Logs.